# Can you label a numeric y-axis in an Excel plot without the major units beginning with the minimum bound?

Tags: excel, charts, axis

I have an Excel combo chart with two axes: The primary axis represents column percentage values with bounds of -100% to 100%, and the secondary axis represents line numeric values with bounds of 5.4 to 13.0.

When I format the secondary axis bounds and units, the axis labels begin at 5.4 with major unit labels of 6.4, 7.4, ... ending at 12.4:

[image: Excel combo chart screenshot]

**Without changing the bounds values, is it possible to have these labels instead appear at 6.0, 7.0, ... ending at 13.0?**

It is important for the bounds of both axes to remain unchanged, as I need the 0% values for the column data to correspond with the 9.2 values of the line data.

If there is not a built-in option for Excel to label y-axis units beginning from the maximum bound instead of the minimum bound, the only workaround I can think of would be to:

1. Mathematically convert the values of the line data to be inverted over 9.2
2. Transform the values to be negative
3. Display the y-axis values in reverse order
4. Remove the negative signs with custom formatting

But that seems ridiculously cumbersome if there is actually a way to have discrete labels on the y-axis for continuous numeric data.

Answer (score 0):

I was overthinking the solution a little bit. A quick workaround for labeling numeric units based on the maximum bound instead of the minimum bound is to:

1. Make a new column that converts the original values to negative values
2. Reselect the chart data to use the new column
3. Format the axis bounds to be `-13` to `-5.4`
4. Select **Values in reverse order**
5. Make the number Format Code `0;0`

Here is the result, with much nicer whole integer labels on the secondary y-axis:

[image: New Excel combo chart]